# Get file codeigniter upload file

Tags: php, arrays, xml, codeigniter

I'm recently uploading multiple file (xml), I'm success on this part. But i've problem when i want to get the `full_path`. I need to access the `full_path` because i need this to save the xml file.

Here is what i get after upload.

```
$file = $this->upload->data('full_path');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($file);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1410.xml
            [file_type] => text/xml
            [file_path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/new_store/assets/file_upload/sales_pos/
            [full_path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/new_store/assets/file_upload/sales_pos/SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1410.xml
            [raw_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1410
            [orig_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-14.xml
            [client_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-14.xml
            [file_ext] => .xml
            [file_size] => 93.38

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1310.xml
            [file_type] => text/xml
            [file_path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/new_store/assets/file_upload/sales_pos/
            [full_path] => D:/xampp/htdocs/new_store/assets/file_upload/sales_pos/SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1310.xml
            [raw_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-1310
            [orig_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-13.xml
            [client_name] => SALESPOS_K-LFJBLP_16-07-13.xml
            [file_ext] => .xml
            [file_size] => 47.43
        )
)
```

and here is for my XML handle

```
$file = $this->upload->data('full_path'); ;
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
```

and i get this error

```
Message: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
```

Comment: yes because $file is array not the file name.

Comment: there are multiple uploads. So there must be multiple file paths. Loop it via `foreach` or `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$xml            = array();
$data = $this->upload->data();
for($x = 0;$x<count($data);$x++)
    {
         $xml[]=simplexml_load_file($data[$x]['full_path']);
    }
echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo I guess

change this :

```
$file = $this->upload->data('full_path'); ;
```

to this :

```
$file = $this->upload->data('full_path');
```

or you can try :

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$file = $data['full_path'];
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
```

for a multiple upload :

```
foreach($file as $each)
{
 $xml=simplexml_load_file($each['full_path']);
}
```

Comment: too many " ; " .  Looks to be a typing error. And codeigniter upload library returns an array from the method data(). ['full_path'] is an index of that array. As for your code , the data you get is an aaray itself for multiple files, So just use foreach loop to loop the array.

Comment: That will not be an problem. try it first A well on this line `$data = $this->upload->data();` you get ***ERROR* Array to string conversion**

Comment: That  part is to show what codeigniter returns using the data() method of upload library. I have already mentioned that in comment.

Comment: i get this error `Message: Undefined index: full_path`

Answer (score 0):

$file is an array not the file. Do like this.

```
foreach($file as $file_val){
  $file_path = $file_val['full_path'];
  $xml=simplexml_load_file($file_path);
}
```